# Quickgraph / Graphsharp nodes layout from left to right

Tags: graph, quickgraph

I am using quickgraph/graphsharp library and try to get such a layout in which i could have all nodes aligned left to right with no overlapping... how it would be possible. Thanks,

http://quickgraph.codeplex.com
http://graphsharp.codeplex.com (graphsharp based on quickgraph)

Comment: have you received any valuable input or answered the question yourself? I would also benefit from an answer to this question.